# How do I make a folder on one laptop visible to another laptop? (both are Win10)

Tags: windows-10

On old Win10 laptop -> File Explorer -> right click a folder -> Properties:

1) Sharing (tab) -> Advanced Sharing -> check Share this Folder -> Permissions -> Everyone -> Full Control -> Ok.

2) Security (tab) -> Authenticated Users -> Edit -> Authenticated Users -> Full Control: Allow -> Ok.

On new Win10 laptop -> File Explorer -> Network --- the old Win10 laptop does not display.  Note that a Win7 laptop does display (was set up a long time ago).

Comment: You need to enable Network discovery on a pc in order to make other pc's see it in the network.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a number of steps in folder sharing. The following method works reliably for me with Windows 10 and earlier operating systems machines.

1. In Advanced Network Sharing, make sure the Network Cards are set to Private (all machines) and that Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing are both enabled (all machines). Make sure Password are being used.
2. Make sure all computers are members of WORKGROUP.
3. If usernames on machines are different, make one main machine and enumerate usernames and passwords from the other machines on this main machine. Use of the same Microsoft Account can avoid this. Earlier systems may not have local accounts, in which case use local accounts as noted earlier.
4. Share the folders you want to the users you enumerated on the main machine.
5. Make sure Home Group is OFF on any machine that supports it. Windows 10 later versions eliminated Home Group.
6. Do not try to share user folders as they are very secure. Use a neutral folder (e.g. c:\Folders_for_sharing)
7. If you wish to use computer names, add them to the local hosts files of the machines. Otherwise use IP addressing
8. Restart the computers and connect as above.

Comment: The answer is obviously that network discovery is turned off. Something that was turned off by default since Windows 8. So step 1 is most likely the only thing that needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Per a phone call from Microsoft --- see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4092694/windows-10-file-sharing-over-a-network --- under "How do I troubleshoot sharing files and folders?" => "If you're on a Wi-Fi network, set it to Private. "

Specifically --- Settings => Network => click on Status (TpLinkName) => Status / Network status => Change connection properties => Network Profile: Private

This fixed everything.

Comment: Using Private setting was in my first step above